# Redirect to other controller when click Tab Bar item

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab Bar that connect to 2 `TableView`, said that `Tab1` go to `Test1TableController`, and `Tab2` go to `Test2TableController`, what I want when I click `Tab2`, it check session first and If the session doesn't exists it will go to other controller before go to `Test2TableController` but my code can't do that

This is my code:

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {

    if(self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex == 1) {
        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
        if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
            let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginController") as! LoginController
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        }
    }

}
```

please help me how to do that ? I have search for several web but can't find like what I want.

Just give me some hint. Thanks

Comment: By the session check you can do code about popTorootviewController. that move you to your application main rootviewcontroller

Comment: @NitinGohel I want go to other controller not the rootcontroller .. is there any way to do that ?

Comment: use break poin did your attached code if condition satisfire if yes than that have to push a login viewcontroller

Comment: @NitinGohel did you mean use break point to see if my code is used or not ? I have try to use print to see my code work or not and nothing wrong, just when I try to pushViewController the code I attached above is not working

Comment: Make sure you have added navigationcontroller to "LoginController" in storyboard and *LoginController* must be a subclass of UIViwController class.